# Degree of similarity

Tags: text, similarity, text-mining

I have to compare two documents and find the degree of similarity .

All i need to do is compare two documents and give a number as a result . The number should depict the degree of similarity (Similar documents will have a larger number)

I want an effective means to perform this process . (The similarity is not measured only on the basics of the similar words , but the context must be taken into consideration too.)

Can anyone suggest an effective algorithm for this process

Comment: there are many resources on this topic. please try searching...

Comment: i read a paper on pairwise similarity. But i am looking at finding effective implementations. Can u suggest one. Please

Comment: Why did this question receive 3 negative votes?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [LSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis) (Latent Sematic Analysis ). This algorithm just checks the similarity of two documents.

Here, you have to learn about the technique called [SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) (Singular Value Decompostion)

If you want to implement the document clustering technique, you can try using Matlab and install Matlab-TMG tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a quick, non-mathematical description, and an implementation (in Java), here's a link to an [n-gram based solution](http://prosehack.wordpress.com/2012/05/25/a-simple-near-duplicate-detection-algorithm/).

Hint: for free text, use a shingle length of 4 or 5 (this is a parameter to the signature generation algorithm)